# Select id on grouped unique set of data

Tags: sql, sqlite

My Problem is showing only id's of grouped unique Datasets. A simple example would serve best:

```
| id | color |
--------------
| 1  | red   |
--------------
| 1  | green |
--------------
| 1  | blue  |
--------------
| 2  | red   |
--------------
| 2  | green |
--------------
| 2  | blue  |
--------------
| 3  | red   |
--------------
| 3  | blue  |
--------------
| 3  | yellow|
--------------
| 3  | purple|
--------------
```

Id 1 and id 2 have the same subset of data (red, green, blue), so the result table should only contain either 1 OR 2:

```
| id |
------
| 1  |
------
| 3  | 
------
```

I guess this relatively basic Problem was asked multiple times but I could not nail the specific keywords which would produce results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although SQLite has `group_concat()`, it won't help here because the order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary.  That is the easiest way to do this.

Instead, we have to think of this relationally.  The idea is to do the following:

1. Count the number of colors that two ids have in common
2. Count the number of colors on each id
3. Select id pairs where these three values are equal
4. Identify each pair by the minimum id in the pair

Then distinct values of the minimum are the list you want.

The following query takes this approach:

```
select distinct MIN(id2)
from (select t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2, count(*) as cnt
      from t t1 join
           t t2
           on t1.color = t2.color
      group by t1.id, t2.id
     ) t1t2 join
     (select t.id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by t.id
     ) t1sum
     on t1t2.id1 = t1sum.id and t1sum.cnt = t1t2.cnt join
     (select t.id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by t.id
     ) t2sum
     on t1t2.id2 = t2sum.id and t2sum.cnt = t1t2.cnt
group by t1t2.id1, t1t2.cnt, t1sum.cnt, t2sum.cnt
```

I actually tested this in SQL Server by placing this `with` clause in front:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as id, 'r' as color union all
      select 1, 'g' union all
      select 1, 'b' union all
      select 2 as id, 'r' as color union all
      select 2, 'g' union all
      select 2, 'b' union all
      select 3, 'r' union all
      select 4, 'y' union all
      select 4, 'p' union all
      select 5 as id, 'r' as color union all
      select 5, 'g' union all
      select 5, 'b' union all
      select 5, 'p'
     )
```

Comment: This seems to work, though I'm still trying to wrap my head around it :-)
Do you know how the Perfomance is regarding big joined tables?
@CL: neat site

Comment: @GnrlKnowledge . . . You'll have to test performance yourself on your systems. The big join is the first one and it might be helped by having an index on `color`.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is set-oriented, so let's try this:

Unique IDs are IDs for which no other ID exists that has an equal set of colors.

To determine whether two IDs have equal sets of colors, we [subtract](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) them from each other (this is what `EXCEPT` does) and test whether the result is empty in both directions:

```
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t) AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t) AS t2
                  WHERE t2.id < t1.id
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT color FROM t WHERE id = t1.id
                                    EXCEPT
                                    SELECT color FROM t WHERE id = t2.id)
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT color FROM t WHERE id = t2.id
                                    EXCEPT
                                    SELECT color FROM t WHERE id = t1.id));
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e00f7/2)

Comment: I like your solution a bit more, very clean and a cool approach!